# How to set a default value in Material UI Timepicker

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set a default value in my material ui time picker, The time value am trying to set as default is formatted this way - **9:00:00 AM**

This is the TimePicker Below

```
           <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <TimePicker
                value={valueFrom}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  onChange(newValue, nameFrom);
               console.log('Time Value: ', newValue.$d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US')); // 9:00:00 AM
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField
                  size="small"
                  variant="outlined"
                  required={valueCheckbox1}
                  {...params} />}
                disabled={!valueCheckbox1 || valueCheckbox2 ? true : false}
                style={{color: 'white'}}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
```

How can I set a default time that comes in this format **9:00:00 AM** on the time picker above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass it as a `Date` so if you put something like this in your code, it should work. Just change day to whatever you need to.

```js
const valueFrom = new Date()
valueFrom.setHours(9)
valueFrom.setMinutes(0)
```